# Firebase .on with Vue without using Vuefire

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I'm trying to implement a real-time connection with Firebase's .on ref, but have no idea where to plug that in or use it in Vue. The tutorials online all use Vuefire to accomplish it, but if I just want to use the Firebase SDK, where can I activate this .on connection in my Vue project and have it work in a two-way data connection real-time?

Hmm.. It didn't seem to work.
This is what I'm using,

```
export default {
    name: 'index',
    data() {
        return {
            id: '1234',
            meData: 'test'
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const database = firebase.database().ref( 'rooms' + this.id );
        database.on( 'value', snapshot => {
            this.meData = snapshot.val();
        });
    }
}
```

I tried testing with push, it works, so the config and firebase is working, but the .on doesn't seem to work. I get no errors too so I'm having a hard time figuring out the issue. =(

Comment: You need to use slashes to access: `ref('/rooms/' + this.id);`

Comment: I tried adding the slashes too, it didn't work. But I changed it to .push and it works. Just the real-time .on doesn't work. =(

Comment: I would like to see your database tree on Firebase. Could you paste the screenshot of it?

Comment: As it is just for testing there is no data in the database atm.
After the .push worked, I also deleted that node to try .on

Comment: `.on` needs a parent branch in your database tree. If you don't have `rooms`, you can't watch it. Before use `.on`, add some trees to watch.

Comment: Added the /rooms and /1234, still, doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I've read that the .ref will create nodes if it doesn't exist so don't think it's the branch issues. Which is why you can do pushes or updates using basically the same scripts. '.on' probably works a little different which is why I'm not too sure how best to implement this... Hmm...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155804/discussion-between-kelvin-zhao-and-izumisy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking to use Firebase in Vue without Vuefire.

Do check out this video!

**Vue 2 & Vuex & Firebase Tutorial - Getting It All Working Together**

https://youtu.be/niPgyv53x8c

Answer (score 2):

At first, always the best option is to use VueFire if you need to use Vue.js and Firebase.

However, if you want to use Vue.js without Vuefire, you can set up the firebase instance in mounted section in your component. Vue component's lifecycle is not the same as the one without Vue, so you better to use lifecycle handler provided by Vue.

```
Vue.component("YourComponent", {
  ...

  mounted() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "apiKey",,
      databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
    });

    const database = firebase.database();

    database.ref('/users/100').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      // Do your business
    });

    ...

    //
    // You can also set up more handlers like above...
    //
  },

  ...
});
```

However, if you want to use two-way binding, it is a little tough. The good point of Vuefire is its easy mixin of Vue component data structure and Firebase instance.

Without Vuefire, the code I can think up would be like this

```
Vue.component("YourComponent", {
  ...

  data() {
    return {
      users: []
    };
  },

  ...

  mounted() {

    //
    // Initialize Firebase SDK and get `database` to use below.
    //

    ...

    database.ref('/users').on('value', (snapshot) => {
      // By using arrow function, the context of `this` here is binded
      // into the current component data `users`.
      this.users = snapshot.val();
    });  
  },

  ...
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. It didn't seem to work.
This is what I'm using,

    export default {
 name: 'index',
 data() {
  return {
   id: '1234',
   meData: 'test'
  }
 },
 mounted() {
  const database = firebase.database().ref( 'rooms' + this.id );
  database.on( 'value', snapshot => {
   this.meData = snapshot.val();
  });
 }
}

I tried testing with push, it works, so the config and firebase is working, but the .on doesn't seem to work. I get no errors too so I'm having a hard time figuring out the issue. =(

Comment: I can't see your source code well. Could you edit your question and add your own code to it?

Comment: Updated in the main question. Can't seem to edit comments.